# scp command asks for a password

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, scp

I am trying to download some files from my server to my local computer. Here is the code I am using:

```
sudo scp -r servername@xxx.xxx.xx.xx:/root/.tsung/log/20131112-1329/ /home/Desktop/
```

and it asks me a password for three times. But I know that I didn't set password for my server but I use .pem file to connect it. How can I use that .pem file with scp command?

edit: I have also tried:

```
scp -i /home/xx/Desktop/xx.pem servername@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/root/.tsung/log/20131112-1329/ /home/besler/Desktop/
```

still asks for the server password.

results of scp -v /home/besler/Desktop/xx.pem servername@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/root/.tsung/log/20131112-1329/ /home/besler/Desktop/

```
Executing: cp '--' '/home/besler/Desktop/beslergokhan.pem' '/home/besler/Desktop/'
cp: `/home/besler/Desktop/beslergokhan.pem' and `/home/besler/Desktop/beslergokhan.pem' are the same file
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host xxx.xx.xx.xx, user ubuntu, command scp -v -d -f -- /root/.tsung/log/20131112-1329/
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xx.xx.xx [xxx.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 9e:92:5a:57:11:fc:79:de:93:be:6d:1b:28:03:d6:4a
debug1: Host 'xxx.xx.xx.xx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
ubuntu@xxx.xx.xx.xx's password:
```

Comment: Does the `pem` file work with the `ssh` command ? (in other words are you sure it is valid?)

Comment: Try with `scp -v`; it probably will show what is happening...

Comment: you can see the updated post which includes the scp -v results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `sudo`, which switches to the *root* user for the command, so the credentials installed in *root*'s ssh configuration are used.

Comment: I did exit from sudo and run it without sudo and with .pem file. here is the result:  WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!
Permissions 0664 for '/home/besler/Desktop/xx.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.

Comment: run `chmod 600 /home/besler/Desktop/beslergokhan.pem` to protect your private key

Answer (score 0):

Location of the pem file is not mentioned in the command. Please use -i option and mentioned the file name in command.

Comment: yes I have just updated the first post. I have tried with it also but still asking for a server password.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I used a **lower case** -p 222 option instead of an **upper case** -P 222
=> The port was not set correctly and therefore the ssh login did not work.

Unfortunately, there is also a lower case -p option and therefore, scp does not show an error.